# Flutter localization default language

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm having some troubles configurating a default language for my flutter app using flutter_localizations. For the moment, I have 2 languages, swedish and english. If the language of the phone is set to swedish, the app is in swedish, and the same with english. However, when it's in neither of these languages the app just resorts back to whatever language was previously used. Instead, I want the app to always resort to english whenever the language of the phone is neither english nor swedish. According to my understanding, the flutter_localizations should either have english as default from the start, or according to how my supportedLocales list is sorted, which is sorted like this: ['en', 'sv,]. Has anyone had the same problem or knows of a workaround? Appreciate any help:)

```
localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''),
          const Locale('sv', ''),
        ],
```

Comment: add code snippet on what you have tried so far

Comment: Added the code from my main.dart

Answer (score 1):

You've likely found the answer already, but if this is not the case, try adding the following callback to your MaterialApp

```
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          for (final supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode) {
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }

          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
```

Comment: Nice solution. Better than others because it doesn't require code modifications when you add more languages ​​in the future. Locale is of type Locale?, so you need to add a question mark. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code snippets will help you.

```
if(PhoneLang == "sv"){
   //Select Language Swedish
}else{

   //In any other cases Select Language English
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a bit more context on this question for future readers. When you changed your device locale to another language (neither en or sv) android pushes this new locale on top of your list of supported locales.

An example:
A) Your initial device languages in order of preference: [en, sv, de]
B) Your new device languages when you select 'de': [de, en, sv]

Flutter will analyse the whole list of device languages and will select the first on that is supported by your app. In the example if you have selected 'de' flutter would fall back to 'en'. Equally if your device's list was [de, sv, en] flutter would choose 'sv'.

It is in general a good idea to leave this the way flutter handles it as it makes the most sense from a user's perspective.

If your device's languages do not have a single locale that is in your list of supported locales (e.g. [de, ar, bn]) flutter will default to the first locale specified in the supported locales list ('en' in your case).
You can rearrange your supported locales list manually if you want to have a different locale at index 0 or, if you are using l10n, you can let flutter it do for you by specifying:

```
preferred-supported-locales: - en
```

in your l10n.yaml file